# Is it possible to restart a for loop to its first iteration?

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, fast-enumeration

In Objective-C, is it possible to restart to the first iteration of a for loop? I don't want to do anything with my objects until I find a "good" object, at which point I want to go back and do stuff with every object up to that good object.

So,

```
bool someflag = false;
for (id object in array)
{
  if(object is good) 
  {
    someflag = true;
    //restart to first object in loop
  }
  if(someflag)
  {
    doStuffWithObject(object);
  }
}
```

Or is there a different/better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Obviously the easy way would be to just have two separate `for` loops -- so if I could get a second opinion telling me that's the best way, that's just what I'll shoot for.  For some reason I have a feeling there's got to be a better way, though.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to do it with two loops? Would make sense to me to do it that way.

Comment: @Fogmeister I have an inkling that there's a better way, but normally I would just use 2 for loops.  Was just curious as to what people could come up with

Comment: Ah, ok, no worries :D

Comment: Don't forget to exit the loop when you get back to the marker object! Might even want to use the good object itself as the flag, so that you know when to break. (I realize this is pseudocode.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not with *fast enumeration*, no (with the exception of [goto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29058056/2057171)), however if you use the *indexed-access* approach, you could:

```
NSUInteger count = [array count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    bool someflag = false;
    id object = array[i];
    if (isgood(object)) 
    {
        someflag = true;
        //restart to first object in loop
        i = 0;
    }
    if(someflag)
    {
        doStuffWithObject(object);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `someflag` to make sure you don't keep resetting the loop repeatedly (or reorganise the if statements to prevent it)

Comment: This doesn't restart properly. You set `i` to 0 but then the `for` loop executes `i++` before going back to the top. So, the next iteration with be with `i` equal to 1. Also, without a `continue` statement, execution will proceed to the `if(someflag) ...` statement, and `someflag` is true, so it will execute `doStuffWithObject(object)` with the current object (before going back to the top.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to do this (rather than using a second loop, which is almost certainly more straightforward), you can use good old `goto`:

```
bool someflag = false;
restart:
for (id object in array)
{
  if(!someflag && object is good) 
  {
    someflag = true;
    goto restart;
  }
  if(someflag)
  {
    doStuffWithObject(object);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `indexOfObjectPassingTest:` to separate the logic in your code between the check (and getting the index) of the 'good' object and the subsequent processing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a while loop for this

```
acutualElement = array.objectAtIndex[0];
int i = 0;
while(actualElemtnt =! null)
{
    if(...){
       do smth;
    } else {
       do smth different;
    }

    if (exit condition reached)
    {
       atualelement = null;
    }        
    else 
    {
       if (i < array.size) i++; //next element in array
       else i = 0; //first element in array
       actualElement = array.objectAtIndex[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, this produces an endless loop until exit condition reached. you wanted to go to 0 when smt. happens. this would work simular. I think @trojanfoe has the better answer ;)